# SDL2 program stops if mouse/keys aren't pressed

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm programming the game Snake in C, using SDL2. I'm trying to make the snake move after a period of time (500 ms or something) and I have a clock that counts the time that has passed while the program is running without fully stopping the game (instead of using SDL_Delay that does that).

This is the function:

```
float relogio (float segundos)
{
  clock_t start = clock();
  clock_t end = clock();
  float sec = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
  sec=sec*1000+ segundos; //total time in seconds
  //printf("sec: %.02f\n", sec );

  return sec;
}
```

and in the main.c

```
if(segundos>= delay) //delay is a variable. right now is at 0.5
    {
      segundos=0;
      moves(cobra, janela);
    }
```

ok, so my problem is that unless my mouse is moving inside the SDL window or I'm pressing keys, the "infinite" loop (untill the variable end_game=0) stops after a period of time. I can see this in terminal because if I'm not doing anything after a while the printf that I have in the beggining of the cycle stop.

**How can I make the program continue working even if I'm not doing anything in the window or pressing keys?**

I hope I was clear, here is a snippet of my while loop in the main function:

```
while(end_game==0)
  {
    printf("ciclo\n" ); // after a while this printf stops print and restarts if I press any key or move my mouse

                               //sdl related functions                      

    segundos=relogio (segundos);

    if(segundos>= delay)
    {
      segundos=0;
      //activates function that makes snake move a block in a certain direction
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(g_pRenderer);                                                                 
  }
```

**EDIT**

```
void game_end int *end_game, int mouse[])
{


  float l3 = 0.025 * LARG +120;             
  float l4 = 0.025 * LARG +200;              
  float sup = 0.2 * AC;
  float inf= 0.8 * AC;


  if(mouse[X] > l3 && mouse[X] < l4 && mouse[Y] > sup && mouse[Y] < inf)
  {
    *end_game = 1;
    game_over(); // this function quits SDL and all closes everything there is to close
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you working on any virtual machine?

Comment: @aneeshjose yes , Oracle VM Virtual Box, running xubuntu

Comment: Can you try to run this in a native os? I think that is the problem.

Comment: I'll have to learn how to do it since I've only worked with c in a Linux environment.I'll try to do it when I get home

Comment: @CPP how do you decide when to quit (i.e. on what condition `end_game` sets to non-0 - you're hitting that condition, most likely)? Also your timing function looks very strange - taking two clock samples one immediately after another is likely to give the same value, or at least very very close. You need to keep previous time sample and compare it with current one.

Comment: @keltar right now I only change end_game value when I click on a button, that is the only place I change it. The clocks give small numbers, but they are different from 0, I'm adding them and I'll eventually get like 500ms and the snake will move

Comment: @CPP the hint was that your button press handling is probably wrong, that's why you get exit when you don't want to. Can't say more without the code.

Comment: @keltar I'm almost 100% sure that it is not it. The end_game variable is set to 0 at the beggining of the main function and it only changes from 0 to 1 and not the other way around. If the problem was there then the game would simply shut down instead of continuing to work if  I move my mouse. Nonetheless, I edited my main post  and added the only part of the code that changes the end-game variable

Comment: @CPP and code that calls this function is?.. If your problem tied to key/mouse events - clearly the most important part here is event handling loop. Or just set a breakpoint at exit function.

Comment: @keltar found the problem, it was somewhat tied with the key/mouse events!!! The problem was with the function SDL_WaitEvent that I had on my main function to detect mouse movements and keys! I replaced it with SDL_PollEvent and now it works fine! Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The function you are using in order to store events, `SDL_WaitEvent()`, waits **until an input is provided**. It means that if no input is provided, the function waits for one. In other words, until you have provided an input to this function, the code that follows won't be executed.

What you want is a function that doesn't block the program. The appropriate function for doing so in SDL is [`SDL_PollEvent()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent). When no input is given, instead of waiting for one, this function returns 0.